# How to read the first line of .txt file?

Tags: javascript, file-upload, split

can anyone one help how to read the first line of .txt file? I have input type file that upload example.txt then I would like to grab the first line from that code. I tried something like this:

```
<input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload"/> MyTest.txt //file name

function confirmFileSubmit(){
    var fileName = $('#fileUpload').val();
    alert($('#fileUpload').split('\n')[0]);
}
```

After I run my code this just outputted file name in alert box. I'm not sure how I can read the content of the file. If anyone can help please let me know.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll need the FileReader for that

```
function confirmFileSubmit(){
    var input  = document.getElementById('fileUpload'); // get the input
    var file   = input.files[0];                  // assuming single file, no multiple
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
        var text = reader.result;                 // the entire file

        var firstLine = text.split('\n').shift(); // first line 

        console.log(firstLine);                   // use the console for debugging
    }

    reader.readAsText(file, 'UTF-8');             // or whatever encoding you're using
                                                  // UTF-8 is default, so this argument 
}                                                 // is not really needed
```

Comment: What is passed in onChange function with the argument 'e'? I tried to alert(e) but I got just [object Object] and I tried e.val() but I got an error for that. If you can explain please. Thanks.

Comment: `e` is the [**event object**](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/), and `event.target` is the targeted element, and `event.target.files` holds the list of files selected. You can't access those files directly, you have to use the `fileReader` to read them, and alerting them will do you no good.

Comment: how I can put that in my javascript not using .on('change',function(e)){} ? I would like to trigger this when I click on my confirmFileSubmit() function.

Comment: You should be getting and reading the files when they are selected, I have no idea what triggers your `confirmFileSubmit`, but if it's a form submitting, the page will redirect before you've read the file, but that's up to you, I've changed the code so it should work a function call instead.

Comment: I have used var input = $('#fileUpload'); and I'm getting TypeError: fileName.files is undefined. What is a difference using JQuery selector in this case and JavaScript? That should not affect this function.

Comment: Of course it affects the situation, jQuery does not return a DOM node, but a jQuery object, and you would have to do `var input = $('#fileUpload').get(0)` to do the same, that's why I used `getElementById` instead

Comment: Ok that explains a lot now. I was confused because my JQuery selector did not work in this case. Thanks for making this clear.

Comment: Is there no way to avoid reading the whole file? I've got huge files (perhaps > 1 GB of text). Just wanted to read the first line.

Comment: @Vineet - Most serverside languages can read just parts of a file, clientside javascript really can't, it reads the entire file before it's accessible.

Comment: Found a way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14842739/2173960. It uses `slice` method on `File` to just get certain bytes. Not the best method since we have to hard-code the upper limit, but we can give a ballpark figure that should work for most.