# Partially reading a file in ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic3, ionic-native

How can I read only a certain number of bytes from a file in Ionic?

I am using the Native [File](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/) plugin but it doesn't seem to handle that. I tried all the file reading methods :

- readAsText(path, file)
- readAsDataURL(path, file)
- readAsBinaryString(path, file)
- readAsArrayBuffer(path, file)

**They all work fine**, but I don't want to have to read the whole file and then extract the  part I need, that would defeat the purpose.

Comment: even though its not ionic, you could try to use javascript: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14842214/html5-filereader-how-to-only-read-the-first-n-characters-of-a-file or maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34544230/read-part-of-remote-file

Comment: As I understand [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) only works with an `<input>` element or with drag and drop. I don't know how to use it with the Native File plugin.